# How to navigate to a specific page in pageview.builder from another page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

```
  LearnLevelButton(
      color: FavoriteButtons[0] ? Colors.orange : Color(0xff7ba6f9),
      text: '1-1',
      onTap: () async {
        await Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Video0_01(

        ),));
      }
```

In the code above, I want to move to a specific page of the video file consisting of pageview. If there is an indexer from Video0_01[0 to 30], when the button is pressed, I want to go directly to the page with a specific number such as Video0_01[2] or Video0_01[30]. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

You should add an argument to your screen with `PageView`. When you navigate to a screen with video, use [`PageController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController-class.html) to set initial page.

Comment: Can I see an example? I knew that too, but I don't know where and how to put the code.

Comment: Can you add code of screen with `PageView`?

Comment: The pageview.builder part has not yet been fully implemented because of the above. Sorry.

Comment: You can start from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58957217/how-do-i-set-the-initial-page-of-pageview-in-flutter).